# Remove item from std::list with only having access to the iterator

Tags: c++, list, iterator, std, erase

std::list is a double linked list. Doesn't that mean that it should be possible to remove an item from a list by only having access to the iterator?

Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.

```
#pragma once

#include <list>


typedef std::list<int> IntList ;
typedef IntList::iterator IntIterator;

class IntHiddenList
{
private:
    IntList list;
public:
    IntIterator AddInt(int x)
    {
        list.push_front(x);
        return list.begin();
    }
};

int main()
{
    IntHiddenList a;

    IntIterator it = a.AddInt(5);


    // How would I go about deleting 5 from the list using only "it"?
}
```

Comment: Yes. that can be done.

Comment: You might show us some of your code and describe better what you are trying to do, because now the questions seems trivially simple, and you probably don't get the answers you are looking for.

Comment: It would be awkward to update the size of the list if this were possible, and the committee considers maintaining easy access to the size of the list to be an important feature.

Comment: Isn't that a bit crippeling for the list? I have a list of pointers to some objects. When deleting the object it could have removed itself from the list by having only the iterator to itself.

Comment: Yes, I'd imagine it's quite crippling.  To be honest, I pretty much never have any use for a linked list, so I don't notice it.  Here's some more information on it though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134836/complexity-of-stdlistsplice-and-other-list-containers

Comment: @bofjas: This used to be more viable, but it turns out allowing what you want is _even more_ crippling to the list.  Namely, that `IntList.size()` took forever to count all the elements.

Comment: Maybe they should have two types of lists then? I don't seem to need size for my project atleast.

Comment: @bofjas: Actually, I agree.  The std lib needs far more container options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, notionally it's possible. However, the standard library does not allow it (it requires the container and iterator to erase).

However you're in luck: boost provides the `boost::instrusive` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/intrusive/list.html) capability to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will still need the list in order to delete an element.

In STL, iterator only holds the pointer to the data, and provides operations to move through the container. You can see good table description [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/).