# List of arrays vs list

Tags: c++, arrays, list

A `list` uses a lot of memory since it adds a pointer to each node, and it is not contiguous, the memory is there fragmented ... A `List of arrays` in my opinion is a lot better. For example if I am managing 100 object, A `list` of `5 array`s of 20 is a lot better than a `List` of 100, only 5 Pointers added vs 100 pointers, we win locality, when using the same `array`, and we have less fragmentation. 
I did some research about this, but I can't find any interesting article about this, so I thought I am missing something.

What can be the benefit of using a `List` over a `List of arrays` ?

**EDIT : This is definetely not Array vs List ... It is more like why putting only one element per list Node if it's possible to put more**

Comment: Why bothering with `std::list` inefficiencies, if you can simply use `std::vector`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array versus linked-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166884/array-versus-linked-list)

Comment: I can't use `std::vector` since I am managing a very large number of large objects

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf This is not Array vs linked list ...

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun _"I can't use `std::vector` since I am managing a very large number of large objects"_ What qualifies `std::list` to be better then?

Comment: Maybe use `std::deque` if you can't use `std::vector`

Comment: If you are talking about Vectors of objects, then this is not even possible since the vector needs to be contiguous, and it is difficult to find such a large free block, a vector of pointers can be compared to list, but then again the list is better since I don't have to reserve memory, and if I don't do that with vector, the vector will be doing some useless copies everytime it needs more memory

Comment: You might want to consider using a [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), it does what you are describing under the hood but presents an `API` like a `std::vector` or an `array`. **quote:** "typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays"

Comment: @Galik I don't really understand your quote, however deque seems like what I am describing, but I still didn't get an answer to my question, that is the advantage of list over deque now

Comment: I didn't have an answer but what strikes me is you have more control with the list of arrays but less convenience and more room for adding bugs. I would generally stick with standard containers unless they prove inadequate. The chances are a standard container will be implemented better and more efficiently that you could come up with yourself - being that they are refined over time and tested by a massive user-base. At least *that* is the theory ;o)

Comment: @Galik Does deque use less memory than list ?

Comment: I am sure that's implementation dependant. But I would imagine it would use less because (like your scheme) it uses a list of contiguous blocks. So each node accounts for many elements whereas a list has a node for each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a valid question as memory location might affect the performance of your program. You can try `std::deque` as some suggested. However, the statement that a typical implementation uses chunks of memory is a general statement about implementation, not standard. It is therefor not guaranteed to be so.

In C++, you can improve the locality of your data through custom allocators and memory pools. Every STL container takes as a parameter allocator. The default allocator is probably a simple wrapper around `new` and `delete` but you can supply your own allocator that uses a memory pool. You can find more about allocators [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B)) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) is a link to the C++ default allocator. [Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/improving-performance-with-custom-pool-a/184406243) is a dr.dobbs article about this topic. A quote from the article:

> If you're using node-based containers (such as maps, sets, or lists), allocators optimized for smaller objects are probably a better way to go.

Only profiling will tell you what works best for your case. Maybe the combination of `std::deque` and a custom allocator will be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Some operations have guaranteed constant-time complexity with `std::list` and not with `std::vector` or `std::deque`.  For example, with `std::list` you can move a subsequence ("splice") of 5000 consecutive elements from the middle of a list with a million items to the beginning (of the same list only!) in constant time.  No way to do that with either `std::vector` or `std::deque`, and even for your list-of-arrays, it will be a fair bit more complicated.

This is a good read: [Complexity of std::list::splice and other list containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10134836/103167)